# What options are there for sending notifications to iphone/android app/webapp?

Tags: iphone, android, notifications

I am developing a system where I wish messages to be sent to users iphone and android phones, without using sms. What are the different options I should consider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

APNS (Apple Push Notification Services) for iPhone, C2DM (Cloud 2 Device Messaging) for Android.  There are also some third-party cross-platform push services available.

Answer (score 1):

You can also turn the way around. The phones can poll if there are new things available on the server. Another option could be a [http server push](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology). Long Polling can also be used.

Comment: Polling is still a totally viable option, but it's not a very popular or trendy one, unfortunately. This person almost certainly has been directed to use push of some sort.

Comment: I also like polling since it frees the server to keep sessions open for a long time. But I grant you the points:-)